# How should I use "as" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> **As a Muslim** my opinion about Christianity is just what the “QURAN” says about it. There are many things about Christianity in the QURAN.

I use http://www.onlinecorrection.com/ to correct my letters. That recognised a mistake about the word "As" on the above sentences. It wrote:

> Grammar
>
> “As” at the beginning of a sentence requires a 2nd clause. Maybe a comma, question or exclamation mark is missing, or the sentence is incomplete and should be joined with the following sentence.

I can't understand what does that mean. Please inform me of how can I correct my mistake. Furthermore, please do me a favour and explain what is the mistake in simple plain English with some examples.

Comment: Yes, you definitely can! You could place a comma after 'Muslim'.

Comment: SovereihnSun, thanks for your advice. I did what you wrote, and then there was no mistake.

Comment: There's no mistake, and a comma is optional, not obligatory. An _as_ phrase like this is called a predicative adjunct. Predicative because it has "my" as predicand, and adjunct because it is an optional item, a supplement in this case. Here's another example: "As a former employee I am saddened by the demise of the company".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a flaw in an English-correction website.  The software should not have marked this sentence as having any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of curiosity I checked whether that site threw an error when I included the comma after "As a Muslim."  It does not. Here the comma is completely optional, as in BillJ's example:

> As a former employee I am saddened by the demise of the company.

However, apparently, their algorithm marks it as *required*.  This only shows that no grammar correction software is perfect.